# Include single quote (apostrophe) in a template's constant value parameter

Tags: resharper

I am creating a template for an HTML-like context.

```
<div data-bind="foo: $bar$"></div>
```

my $bar$ parameter should be a "comma delimited list of values" (one per line):
['A']
['A', 'B']
['B']

I figured that I can use \, to escape a comma (line #2). But I can't figure out how to include `'`

I can open .DotSettings file and change:

`list("['A']...")`
with
`list("[\'A']...")` and then it works, until I save the template from VS again.

Note, I did try feeding `[\'A\']` to the template editor, but it replaces `\` with `\\` in the file, and when template is expanded - it just puts the name of the parameter, rather than offering a choice from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug in ReSharper, unfortunately. I've opened a ticket that you can track and vote on: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-441077